# Using html forms on AWS (EC2 instance)

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, forms

I receive the following error when I click submit for my form

```
<Error><Code>InvalidArgument</Code><Message>Invalid argument.</Message><Details>The requested project was not found.</Details></Error>
```

My home html file is at /var/www/html/index.html in my ec2 instance.
My php script is at /var/www/html/php/email_me.php in my ec2 instance

This is my php script

```
<?php
if($_POST["submit"]) {
    $recipient="sam.germain@usask.ca"; //Enter your mail address
    $subject=$_POST["Subject"]; //Subject 
    $sender=$_POST["Name"];
    $senderEmail=$_POST["Email"];
    $message=$_POST["Message"];
    $mailBody="Name: $sender\nEmail Address: $senderEmail\nSubject:$subject\n\nMessage: $message";
    mail($recipient, $subject, $mailBody);
    sleep(1);
    header("Location:http://www.oysterhop.com/"); // Set here redirect page or destination page
}
?>
```

This is the beginning line of my form for the html file

```
<form action="php/email_me.php" method="post" role="form" aria-label="contact form" class="form_style-wrapper" >
```

But I really don't think the problem is in the php or html code, I just can't figure out how to run a php script in my ec2 instance

I've already installed php5 and libapache2-mod-php5